# What is the meaning of injective $g\circ f$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given $f:A→B$ and $g:B→C$ , $f, g$ are full (not partial).

What is the meaning of injective $g\circ f$? Does it mean that both, $f$ and $g$ are injective?

Comment: What do you mean by "full (not partial)"?  Are you meaning to say that $f$ and $g$ are both surjective?  Or are you simply meaning that $f$ and $g$ are functions.

Answer (score 2):

$g\circ f$ injective implies $f$ is injective. This is most easily seen by contraposition: if $f$ is not injective, $g\circ f$ *cannot* be injective.

Nothing can be said about $g$ – unless $f$ is bijective.

Similarly, if $g\circ f$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective, and nothing can be said about $f$, unless $g$ is bijective.

Comment: In your final sentence, you meant to say $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Oops! One of my many slips. Thanks for pointing it, I'll correct it at once.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that the concatenation is. That is a map $g\circ f: A\to C, a\mapsto c=g(f(a))$